# How to change input attribute "values" in codeigniter on submit

Tags: codeigniter

This is my code snippet

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $details[0]->invoice_id;?>" name="invoice_id">
```

on submit I need to change the value by increment of 1 and pass it to controller `$invoice_id=$this->input->post('invoice_id',true);`.
This code is just updating with same invoice_id in database table. 
Please help me to write a code that will increment value on each submit.

Comment: <?php echo $details[0]->invoice_id +1 ;?>

Comment: It should increment...On next submit it will be 2. From there onwards it will be 2 for each increment

Comment: As per my suggestion first time when submit, store that incremented value in session and next time when it will submited increment that session 
value not hidden value.

Comment: you said invoice_id is primary key so it will be autoincremented and if you want to use that id somewhere use return last inserted id. `$this->db->insert_id();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You all for your precious time. I got the result finally.
In model I wrote a function to extract the invoice_id

```
function get_details()
    {
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from `invoice_details` ORDER BY invoice_id DESC");
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        if($query->num_rows()>=1)
            return $query->result()[0]->invoice_id;
    }
```

and in the controller I extract this invoice_id through

```
$invoice_id=$this->invoice_m->get_details();
```

and pass this value.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use auto increment in database?
if not, use something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $details[0]->invoice_id;?>" name="invoice_id">
```

on controller use:

```
$invoice_id = $this->input->post('invoice_id');
$invoice_id = $invoice_id++;
```

if it receives 1 on first line, will be 2 on second line... You just need to use the $invoice_id anywhere you need.

Comment: invoice_id is foreign key in the table from_details. So AUTO ICREMENT is not possible. by default in the view the value of invoice_id is assigned  to the value of the first record of the table invoice_details, then i need to identify the user based on the invoice_id on each submit in from_details table.

Comment: <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $details[0]->invoice_id;?>" name="invoice_id">. The problem replies in this line. Because it is just taking the same data each time. I need a code in such a way that on next submit it will be like <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $details[1]->invoice_id;?>" and so on

Comment: Can you post the controller/view? i was not understand what you did mean when you say you cant submit an $var ++ value.

Comment: Look, just a small piece of basic PHP, maybe you know, but it worst a try. You`re getting from $details[0]->invoice-id an value = 0. if you need it when you submit 1, you just need render at form in new value. and not on old value. or you can use 2 hidden with old and new value. using $vars.

Comment: Ex. $var_old_value = $details[0]->invoice_id; 
On view use echo $var_old_value. you will got same result as actually, but if you do $var_new_value = $var_old_value ++; you will get it by actual value + 1.